# What is the most common greeting phrase, used by service attendants, when a customer pulls into a gas station for fuel?

Tags: word-choice

Attendants yell out a greeting when customers get gasoline for their cars. Please provide me with some phrases and meanings.

Comment: I think as a question it is too broad. Depending on the gas station, there may be different things that attendants "yell out". Also, it is not clear, whether you are looking for things *only* at a gas station, or also for something that could be said in a restaurant, say. Or whether you're looking for something specific you've heard at a gas station (which you haven't described).

Comment: My question specifically addresses gas stations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least here in Kansai I usually hear them say something like:

> はーい、オーライオーライオーライ... はいっ、オッケーでーす！
>   いらっしゃい（ませ）、現金レギュラー満タンで！？

or

> こちらへどうぞー、オーライオーライオーライ... はいっ、オッケーでーす！
>   いらっしゃい（ませ）、カード・現金？レギュラー満タンで！？

---

Phrases and meanings:

- はーい -- It's like "Here" or "This way". Drawing the customer's attention and guiding them to the right direction.
- こちらへどうぞ -- "(Move your car) this way, please."
- オーライオーライオーライ... -- "Alright, alright..." Telling them to move the car forward.
- はいっ -- "Now" or "Here", indicating that the car has now come to the right position.
- オッケーです -- Literally "It is OK". Telling them to stop the car.
- いらっしゃい(ませ) -- "Welcome (to the store)" or "Hello". General greeting for welcoming customers.
- 現金レギュラー満タンで --- Common phrase heard at gas stations. "By cash, fill it up with regular?"
- カード、現金 -- "(Are you paying) by cash or credit card?"

Comment: 「おいでやすぅ～」とか「満タンでよろしゅおすかぁ」とか言わへん？こういう大声での掛け声って、なんで地方色出にくいんやろ。会社の方針以外の理由があるような気ぃしてしゃーないねんけど。

Comment: 「おいでやす」「～おす(か)」って、フツーのちっこい店でも言わへん。舞妓・芸子さんとかくらいしか言わへんのちゃうかな。ガソリンスタンドでは「へい　らっしゃい！おおきに毎度！」くらいは言うてるかも。